# In Brillouin-Wigner perturbation theory, how to choose the correct energy from all the solution?

Tags: perturbation-theory

I'm currently studying the Brillouin-Wigner theory from the book "Atomic many-body theory" of I. Lindgren & J. Morrison.

The energy $E$ of the **perturbated** state $|\alpha>$ is linked to the **unperturbed** energy $E_0$ of the state $|\alpha>$ and the **unperturbed** eneregy $E_0^\beta$ of all the states $|\beta>$ such as $\alpha \neq \beta$ with the formula:

$$
E = E_0 + E^{(1)} + E^{(2)} + E^{(3)} + ...
$$
with:
$$
E^{(1)} = <\alpha|V|\alpha>
$$
$$
E^{(2)} = \sum_{\beta \neq \alpha}\frac{<\alpha|V|\beta><\beta|V|\alpha>}{(E-E_0^\beta)}
$$
$$
E^{(3)} = \sum_{\beta , \gamma \neq \alpha}\frac{<\alpha|V|\beta><\beta|V|\gamma><\gamma|V|\alpha>}{(E-E_0^\beta)(E-E_0^\gamma)}
$$

Which means that the number of solution, at second order, for $E$ is equal to N = 1+number of different values for $E_0^\beta$, since we get a polynom of degree N on the numerator (put all terms on the same denominator and on the same side of the equal sign and let's assume that $E \neq E_0^\beta$ for the sake of simplicity).

We can of course eliminate the complex solutions, but when several real solutions remains, how do we know which one is the correct energy ?

Subsidiary question, the book mention the algorithm of Newton-Raphson procedure to find solutions but my edition was published in 1982. Would you still choose the Newton-Raphson algorithm today, or are there better options ? (I see that the package `Roots` for the language Julia provides some alternatives)

Comment: The energy equation in BWPT is usually solved iteratively, i.e insert $E_0$ instead of $E$ in the RHS and evaluate to a given order. This is your new "guess" for $E$. Then, insert this into RHS instead of $E$, evaluate, and so on. Are you asking about what happens when this iteration gives different results for different starting guesses?

Comment: Yes, how do I know that using $E_0$ as the initial guess will lead the algorithm to the wanted solution ? Also, when the polynom is of low order, I can solve it anatically, getting all solution immediately without needing Newton-Raphson algorithm...

Comment: Well, $E_0$ is the exact energy when the perturbation is off, and if perturbation theory is to be meaningful then the changes to it should be "small" in some sense, which is why we expand in powers of a small parameter. So for me $E_0$ is an intuitive starting point.

Comment: And the Newton-Raphson method is just a numerical way of finding the roots of a complicated polynomial. I'm not sure I see a huge advantage in having analytical expressions for these to very low order in the perturbation theory.